# How to add a border to an image on hover in D3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am using D3 where leaves of a Pack layout are represented by images added like this:

```
svg.selectAll("image.leaves")
.data(nodes, keyFunction)
.enter().append("g")
.append("image")
.attr("class", "leaves")
.attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
     if (d.fileType == "Document")
         return "document.png";
     return "other.png";
});
```

I would like to add a black border to this image on hover, but I am not able to do so with:

```
.leaves:hover { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

as it just does nothing.

If anyone can help me in the right direction, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, SVG elements do not accept the same style properties that HTML elements do. You can find a list of valid style properties for SVG elements [**HERE**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties).

To make a border, you can use a `<rect>` element with the same dimensions as your image, and add it to the `<g>` element you created in the enter selection:

```js
// store the entering group as a variable
var imageEnter = svg.selectAll('.leaves')
  .data(nodes, keyFunction)
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'leaves');

// append the image
imageEnter.append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {
     return d.fileType === 'Document' ? 'document.png' : 'other.png';
  });

// append the border rect
imageEnter.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'image-border')
  .attr('width', widthOfYourImage)
  .attr('height', heightOfYourImage);
```

Now you can use your css to change the `stroke` property of the border rect when it is hovered. Since it is a `<rect>`, the hover state will be active when the cursor is over any part it, even if its fill is set to transparent, which does away with any need to use the hover-state of the parent to change the style of the child. Nice and simple:

```css
.image-border {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: transparent;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.image-border:hover {
  stroke: black;
}
```

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/rumuj/1/edit?css,js,output) is a simplified example.

Comment: Hi @jshanley, thank you so much for such a detailed answer! I marked it as the correct answer so long, because I can see it works from the example. Will try it out!